# Stopping overlapped textures from flickering

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a maze game project using Unity latest version. In this case I use cubes as walls and cube has a texture as image below. In some cases cubes are over lapping each other. These overlapped areas shows flickering while in editor and also in game. I search google for solution but no luck. I can try to do something to avoid overlapping these walls. But I need to know how to stop this flickering when textures are overlapping.

Here is the Screenshot of my wall
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact problem, with cornering walls, I found a solution by myself and want to share it here for other people. (I'm aware this post is very old)

If you are placing the wall manually, then just do a small offset, even 0.01 will remove the flickering.

If you are instantiating the walls, then just create this offset at the moment of the instantiation. You can also add a random offset:

```
   var randomOffset = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0.01f, 0.03f);

    // Fix Wall flickering
    itemToBeInstantiated.transform.position = new Vector3(targetPosition.x, targetPosition.y, targetPosition.z + randomOffset); ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead creating walls using cube ,try to make 3d model using Maya or 3ds max then map the uv's. I mean the wall uv and all

Comment: Thanks for reply. The thing is I'm not good for 3D modeling. just trying to do things with standers unity assets.